# Asp.NET Identity Core IsInRole InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, .net-4.5

I have this code:

```
...
var _context = new MyDbContext();     
var _userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(_context));
...
public bool IsInRole(string userId, string roleName)
{
    return _userManager.IsInRole(userId, roleName); //InvalidOperationException
}
```

Throws this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Sequence contains more than one element

Visual Studio 2015

.NET 4.5

Microsoft AspNet Identity Core 2.2.1

Entity Framework 6

[image: InvalidOperationException]

Comment: Do you have a custom UserManager implementation?

Comment: Or does you database perhaps have some bad data in it?

Comment: There were duplicated rows in my IdentityRoles table. Removing these solved the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, but next time wait for the person who suggested the possibility to add the answer so they can get the recognition :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are duplicated names in the IdentityRoles table:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[IdentityRoles]
```

[image]

Deleting the unnecessary rows solved the problem.

Comment: Something went wrong in your database. Make sure that Name column has a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT